# Подсчёт наработанного времени в БД Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, запрос

Возникла такая задача: запросом в БД PostgreSQL необходимо подсчитать количество наработанного времени в формате HH:mm:ss за определенный период с условием что заданный параметр более определенного порога.

Пример БД:

[image: Пример в БД]

То есть нужно суммировать разницу во времени, где значение current > 100 и вывести результат в формате HH:mm:ss, даже если количество часов будет превышать 24

Comment: А что значит "суммировать время", что должно получиться например при сложении '2020-08-19 13:48:22' и '2020-08-19 13:48:39' ?

Comment: А вообще у вас три вопроса в одном. ограничить выборку только current > 100 - добавить это условие в where, получить только сумму - использовать sum() (определившись что же мы суммируем, потому что суммировать можно только числа) и как потом вывести в нужном формате (зависит от того что суммировали и в каких единицах)

Comment: Суммировать разницу во времени, если значение current > 100. Спасибо что поправили.

Comment: Разницу во времени между чем и чем ? Если подряд идущих событий, то какую дату считать следующей для 16:22:22.5, ту что 16:22:26.9 или пропустив current <= 100 и брать разницу с 16:22:33.1 ? или вообще взять минимальную и максимальную среди всей выборки и получить разницу между ними

Comment: Разницу между 16:22:22.5 и 16:22:33.1 суммировать не нужно, т.к. между ними строки, где current < 100

Comment: Тогда выходит надо взять сразу разницу 16:22:22 - 13:48:22 так как между ними нет строк < 100 и добавить к ней разницу 16:22:41 - 16:22:33 ? Короче приведите полный пример расчета для показанной картинки

Comment: Я рассчитывал время на стороне клиента с помощью ЯП, алгоритм был следующий: current текущей строки, сравнивается с current следующей строки, если current текущей и следующей строк >= 100, то вычисляем разницу во времени между ними и суммируем. Сейчас возникла задача выполнять это на стороне БД с помощью запроса либо встроенного функционала postgreSQL, увы у меня не большой опыт работы с СУБД.

Comment: @heavenbeyond91 уточнения по тому, какой все таки алгоритм вы пытаетесь реализовать, делайте в тексте вопроса кнопкой "править", а не в комментариях. Вы хотите, чтобы вам помогли, так уважайте и цените время коллег, чтоб им не нужно было выискивать в комментариях все уточнения вопроса.

Comment: @heavenbeyond91 Но это абсолютно то же самое, что написал я. Вот пример на частичной выборке https://pastebin.com/8qfcSUvw  Все так ? Можно конечно и по вашему пути пойти, берем все строки и на каждой с помощью lag() получаем значение колонки из предыдущей строки и дальше case сравниваем current, если больше 100 получаем разницу между представлением в секундах (`extract(epoch from timestamp)`, потом оборачиваем внешним запросом и суммируем. Остается перевести обратно в часы минуты секунды.